# Not able to access the Redux state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-firebase, react-redux-i18n

TypeError: Cannot read property 'handle' of undefined.

```
render() {
const {
  classes,
  user: {
    credentials: { handle, createdAt, imageUrl, bio, website, location },
    loading,
    authenticated,
  },
} = this.props;
```

> Props values

[enter image description here][1]

Redux State values
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqvQt.png

Comment: Probably when you render the component the redux state has not changed and the user is not set. Try to have another property that watches if the user request is done.

Comment: @Slavian thanks mate. I solved this using functional component and now it is working fine.